# How to loop through nested JSON and append in HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

I am trying to loop through a JSON and append it to HTML in a nested way. What I am trying to do is add a Header tag  for the title of the object and have  tags for the titles of items. Some objects might not have the *items* as empty too. I am guessing a nested loop is required and I've tried implementing it. The JSON looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Hello",
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/login/notes/1/",
        "description": "Hello nice",
        "created_at": "2019-08-10T06:02:55.468315Z",
        "created_by": "Dude",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/login/items/1/",
                "title": "baby's toy",
                "note": "http://localhost:8000/login/notes/1/"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/login/items/2/",
                "title": "baby's toy",
                "note": "http://localhost:8000/login/notes/1/"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/login/items/4/",
                "title": "postman5",
                "note": "http://localhost:8000/login/notes/1/"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "abc",
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/login/notes/2/",
        "description": "asad",
        "created_at": "2019-08-10T15:23:53.074848Z",
        "created_by": "dude2",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/login/items/5/",
                "title": "Parrot Toy",
                "note": "http://localhost:8000/login/notes/2/"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

I've tried

```
 fetch('http://localhost:8000/login/notes/?format=json',{mode: 'cors'})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    var output='';
  var final='';
  var semif='';
  var darif='';

      for (var i in data) {

      output+=i+'<h2>'+data[i].title +'</h2>'
      for(j in data[i].items){
      final+='<li>'+data[i].items[j].title+'</li>'

    }
    semif=output+final



      }

     document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=darif

  });
```

HTML

```
<p id="test">

</p>
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
  <h5>baby's toy</h5>
  <h5>baby's toy</h5>
  <h5>postman5</h5>
<h1>abc</h1>
  <h5>parrot's toy</h5>
```

Comment: If you want the elements inside the items object to have have headers, you need to wrap them inside h5 tags (you only wrapped with a li tag). What's more, I would check against the property items, as you said it might not exist (you could get an exception directly accessing it).

Comment: It still doesn't work even if i change it to <h5>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/login/notes/?format=json',{mode: 'cors'})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {

   var html = '';

   data.forEach(listItem => {

        const h1 = `<h1> ${listItem.title} </h1>`;
        html+=h1;

        listItem.items.forEach(item=> {
            const h5 = `<h5> ${item.title} </h5>`;
            html+=h5;
        });
   });

   document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=html;
});
```

I think you may use it.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly advise against doing lengthy string concatenations. Strings are immutable objects and they can put unnecessary burden on your system.

In addition, using `map` and `join` is much more elegant and easier to read.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Hello",
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/login/notes/1/",
        "description": "Hello nice",
        "created_at": "2019-08-10T06:02:55.468315Z",
        "created_by": "Dude",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/login/items/1/",
                "title": "baby's toy",
                "note": "http://localhost:8000/login/notes/1/"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/login/items/2/",
                "title": "baby's toy",
                "note": "http://localhost:8000/login/notes/1/"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/login/items/4/",
                "title": "postman5",
                "note": "http://localhost:8000/login/notes/1/"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "abc",
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/login/notes/2/",
        "description": "asad",
        "created_at": "2019-08-10T15:23:53.074848Z",
        "created_by": "dude2",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/login/items/5/",
                "title": "Parrot Toy",
                "note": "http://localhost:8000/login/notes/2/"
            }
        ]
    }]

const result = data.map(el => {
  return `<h1>${el.title}</h1>` + el.items.map(el => `<h5>${el.title}</h5>`).join("")
}).join("")
console.log(result)
```